# why i can't run command "npm update" in my ionic project?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, capacitor

I can't run command npm update or npm install in my ionic project. this is an error that I get.

[image]

and here is my "ionic info"

[image]

Comment: Try to remove package-lock.json and try again maybe?

Comment: I have tried, but it is still error.

Comment: Can you share the project folder structure and the path where you run the npm update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.....
This kind of stuff happens exactly when you continuously remove `package-lock.json` in order to update some packages, you never... ever... delete `package-lock.json`, unless the project is very new and small, it's always the last solution because it can cause exactly what you are facing `multiplied by 100`. It has `lock` in name because it has to be fixed, because it holds the exact versioning of your dependency tree. you cannot recreate it, because in order to recreate it you have to use `npm install` and it may not install dependency tree as it should!. That is why you should use `npm ci` instead of `npm install` when generating `node_modules`, because  `npm ci` fires error if there is no `package-lock.json` checks package syncronization betwen `package-lock.json and package.json`, removes old version of `node_modules`, checks dependency version mismatches, and a lot more...

Now, you should execute the command with `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` as recommended, and pray that works, if it works you should have in mind that this is a temporary solution, what `legacy-peer-deps` does is tell npm to `ignore dependency conflict` and continue instalation. This can also happen, because of some `deprecated package`, you should check the docs for the package in question. If it doesn't work, try downgrading `node.js` to 15, but this would also be temporary solution. The proper solution is to manually fix the dependency conflict

Comment: Given a package.json you can regenerate the package-lock.json.  Also if you use yarn it is recommened to delete package-lock.json

Comment: Of course you can, the problem is that in a whole lot of cases it isn't regenerated correctly. You cannot do that in a big project, you end up with a mess. package.json doesn't hold exact versions of your dependencies, it holds package versions with prefixes `^` and `~` and that's where the problem lies. They have a meaning and this can cause big differences when regenerating package-lock.json, compared to previous version of it. You may fix one thing but mess up whole dependency tree.